# Error in Ortools installation (x86) - mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64h')

Tags: python, or-tools

I am recieving this error when installing and running

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
```

after following this guide. https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/python/mac

I am using a 2019 MacBook Pro (V 12.4, Python 3.9.4), which is x86, and not M1. However, the error is regarding the module not being compatible with M1 Macs, which should not apply. All information available online is about the error regarding M1 Macs. Any help is appreciated!

```
ImportError: dlopen([path], 0x0002): tried: '[path]/my_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ortools/linear_solver/_pywraplp.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64h'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M1 only wheel package have been named `universal2` by pypa tools so any intel based mac currently pull it -> runtime issue.

On my way to fix our upload and release script, sorry for the inconvenience...

note: issue tracked in https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3436
note2: one workaround would be to download "locally" the correct wheel package then install it `cd <you_download_dir>; python -m pip install --find-links=. ortools`

Comment: And fixed as new wheels have been pushed.

Answer (score 0):

try forcing the arch to x64_64.

For some reason, brew python tags aarch64 wheel as universal, and x86_64 as x86_64.